# Unity Skinned Mesh Renderer breaks mesh surface when animating

Tags: unity-game-engine

When the bone transforms of my SkinnedMeshRenderer in Unity rotate and move, the surface skin of the rigged mesh sometimes splits up, with the splices leaving open the mesh (so you'd be able to look inside it, if it was using a doublesided shader). Is there a generic way to avoid this, to have triangle points always remain merged? Thanks!

Comment: That generally means something is wrong with your model in the modeling package. Some vertices are split in the modeling package and don't share the same bone influences.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried various "clean up/ repair/ merge points" approaches in Lightwave on the object ( http://anyland.com/hand.zip ), to no avail. Do you know any good programs/ features to investigate?

Comment: If it was me I'd try deleting everything from my model except 2 polygons or 2 quads that exhibit the issue. I'd then print out all the data one way or another see if my intuition matches reality. In other words that there really are vertices that should have the same weights to the same bones but don't. I'd then try to figure out why.

Comment: For reference, switching to "Closest Point" the skinning method in Puppet3D did the job and solved it. Since it turned out to be something in the scope of Puppet3D, it might not be a fitting answer to my question/ I may need to delete my question. Not sure.

Answer (score -1):

This happens in Unity, but in Unreal the same model works fine. It's an issue with Unity, not the model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).